# Avoid Attester Slashing - Etherum2.0

Tags: eth-2.0, validators, slashings, slashing-detectors, attestations

According to specs, for attester slashing i need to compare the epoch with previous epoch

my question is- is it enough to check that the current epoch with the last one i saved using is_slashable_attestation_data, or do i need to save all the slots since my first validator was created?

Also, do i use the same data for all my validator clients (and their validators)? i mean if i actually can save only the last epoch, i need to save it for each validator or one for all of them?

I was based on this info: https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/validator.md#how-to-avoid-slashing

Comment: Eth2 clients already do this for you. Are you trying to write your own client or modify one?

Comment: i am writing a remote signer

Comment: Try asking at reddit.com/r/ethstaker  If you get an answer, please post it here too :)